# smarty code get one image only

Tags: php, joomla, task-parallel-library, smarty

This current piece of Smarty code brings up he whole gallery.

```
{$current_item->get('gallery')}
```

I need it to bring up only the first or (1) image from it?

Any ideas on how I can do this ?

Comment: This really doesn't give enough information for anyone to help you.

Comment: Can you provide more information about what is it that you want..